# Writing a function or loop that combines rows with duplicate character strings in a large data frame containing NAs

Tags: r, function, loops

TL:DR I am trying to do two things here - write a loop or a function to iterate over a ***very large*** data frame that includes figuring out how combine the dissimilar values in duplicate rows without losing any columns.

I have a very large data frame that looks kind of like the example below. I want to write either a function or a loop that will return one row per `ShopperID`, and combines all colors into one entry in the `Colors` column, and all the produce into one entry the `Produce` column, per that `ShopperID`, and keep all of the other columns.

```
## # A tibble: 13 × 6
##    FirstName LastName ShopperID Colors               Produce             ZipCode
##    <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>                <chr>               <chr>  
##  1 Clayton   Kershaw  44839     Red, Blue            Tomato, Corn, Pars… 90001  
##  2 Clayton   Kershaw  44839     Yellow               Potato, Leek        90001  
##  3 Clayton   Kershaw  44839     Magenta, Green, Lime Grapes, Limes       <NA>   
##  4 Clayton   Kershaw  44839     Black, Red           Basil, Mango, Onion 90001  
##  5 Justin    Turner   38227     Turquiose, Ecru      Olives, Rosemary    90002  
##  6 Justin    Turner   38227     Red, Pink, Orange    Broccoli, Eggplant  90002  
##  7 Justin    Turner   38227     Green                Peas                90002  
##  8 Justin    Turner   38227     Black                Lettuce, Cabbage    <NA>   
##  9 Justin    Turner   38227     Tan                  Daikon              <NA>   
## 10 David     Freese   78559     Sky, Cardinal        Turnip, Kiwi, Napa  90003  
## 11 David     Freese   78559     Cream, Blue          Sprouts, Peppers    90003  
## 12 Will      Smith    37446     Purple, Grey         Jalapenos, Cilantr… 90004  
## 13 Mookie    Betts    27734     Red, Blue, Navy      Edamame, Strawberr… 90005
```

The output that I am looking for is this:

```
## # A tibble: 5 × 6
##   FirstName LastName ShopperID Colors                            Produce ZipCode
##   <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <chr>                             <chr>   <chr>  
## 1 Clayton   Kershaw  44839     Red, Blue, Yellow, Magenta, Gree… Tomato… 90001  
## 2 Justin    Turner   38227     Turquiose, Ecru, Red, Pink, Oran… Olives… 90002  
## 3 David     Freese   78559     Sky, Cardinal, Cream, Blue        Turnip… 90003  
## 4 Will      Smith    37446     Purple, Grey                      Jalape… 90004  
## 5 Mookie    Betts    27734     Red, Blue, Navy                   Edamam… 90005
```

I figured out how to do part of this, but the below code doesn't address the instances where there is a `ZipCode` missing from one of the entries that are being combined. I don't want to drop the rows with `NA`s.

When I run the code without putting `ZipCode` in the `group_by` call, it returns the result I am looking for except it drops the `ZipCodes` column entirely and I don't want to do that either.

```
SO_Example_1 %>% 
  group_by(ShopperID, FirstName, LastName, ZipCode) %>% 
  summarise(Produce = paste(Produce, collapse = ","), (Colors = paste(Colors, collapse = ","))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Here is the output of that code:

```
## # A tibble: 7 × 6
##   ShopperID FirstName LastName ZipCode Produce            (Colors = paste(Colo…¹
##   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>              <chr>                 
## 1 27734     Mookie    Betts    90005   Edamame, Strawber… Red, Blue, Navy       
## 2 37446     Will      Smith    90004   Jalapenos, Cilant… Purple, Grey          
## 3 38227     Justin    Turner   90002   Olives, Rosemary,… Turquiose, Ecru,Red, …
## 4 38227     Justin    Turner   <NA>    Lettuce, Cabbage,… Black,Tan             
## 5 44839     Clayton   Kershaw  90001   Tomato, Corn, Par… Red, Blue,Yellow,Blac…
## 6 44839     Clayton   Kershaw  <NA>    Grapes, Limes      Magenta, Green, Lime  
## 7 78559     David     Freese   90003   Turnip, Kiwi, Nap… Sky, Cardinal,Cream, …
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fill()` function from `tidyr` is one way to handle your issue. I also corrected the issue with your Colors column name.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Example data
SO_Example_1 <- read.table(text = "FirstName;LastName;ShopperID;Colors;Produce;ZipCode
Clayton;Kershaw;44839;Red, Blue;Tomato, Corn, Parsnip;90001  
Clayton;Kershaw;44839;Yellow;Potato, Leek;90001  
Clayton;Kershaw;44839;Magenta, Green, Lime;Grapes, Limes;   
Clayton;Kershaw;44839;Black, Red;Basil, Mango, Onion;90001  
Justin;Turner;38227;Turquiose, Ecru;Olives, Rosemary;90002  
Justin;Turner;38227;Red, Pink, Orange;Broccoli, Eggplant;90002  
Justin;Turner;38227;Green;Peas;90002  
Justin;Turner;38227;Black;Lettuce, Cabbage;   
Justin;Turner;38227;Tan;Daikon                ;  
David;Freese;78559;Sky, Cardinal;Turnip, Kiwi, Napa;90003  
David;Freese;78559;Cream, Blue;Sprouts, Peppers;90003  
Will;Smith;37446;Purple, Grey;Jalapenos, Cilantro;90004  
Mookie;Betts;27734;Red, Blue, Navy;Edamame, Strawberry;90005", sep = ";", header = TRUE)


result <- SO_Example_1 %>% 
  group_by(ShopperID) %>%
  fill(ZipCode, .direction = "downup") %>%
  group_by(ShopperID, FirstName, LastName, ZipCode) %>%
  summarise(Produce = paste(Produce, collapse = ","),
            Colors = paste(Colors, collapse = ","), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  ungroup()

result
# A tibble: 5 × 6
#   ShopperID FirstName LastName ZipCode Produce                                    Colors
#       <int> <chr>     <chr>      <dbl> <chr>                                      <chr> 
# 1     27734 Mookie    Betts      90005 "Edamame, Strawberry"                      Red, …
# 2     37446 Will      Smith      90004 "Jalapenos, Cilantro"                      Purpl…
# 3     38227 Justin    Turner     90002 "Olives, Rosemary,Broccoli, Eggplant,Peas… Turqu…
# 4     44839 Clayton   Kershaw    90001 "Tomato, Corn, Parsnip,Potato, Leek,Grape… Red, …
# 5     78559 David     Freese     90003 "Turnip, Kiwi, Napa,Sprouts, Peppers"      Sky, …
```

Comment: @pleasecallmegarry - you are most welcome. Pro tip for when you ask your next question: you will get a faster response if you employ the awesome power of `dput()`. So in the case of this question, you would do something like `dput(head(df), 13)` where df is  the name of your data. Then, copy the result into your question. It'll look something like `structure(...)`. The advantage of `dput()` is that it returns an exact copy of your data that can be easily recreated. Thanks